# Using jspdf & angularfire2 storage

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-storage, angularfire2, jspdf

I use angular cli 1.6 angularfire2 and firebase storage.

I want to register my html template in pdf to do this I use:

```
    html2canvas( data ).then(canvas => {  

      var imgWidth =297;
      var pageHeight = 210;    
      var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;  
      var heightLeft = imgHeight;  
      const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')  
      var file = new jspdf('l', 'mm', 'a4'); // A4 size page of PDF  
      var position = 2;  
     pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight)  
}
```

and I use angularfire2 to save it in firebase storage: the documentation gives this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireStorage } from 'angularfire2/storage';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  <input type="file" (change)="uploadFile($event)">
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private storage: AngularFireStorage) { }
  uploadFile(event) {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    const filePath = 'name-your-file-path-here';
    const task = this.storage.upload(filePath, file);
  }
}
```

I tried this:

```
    public captureScreen()  {  
var data = document.getElementById('contentToConvert'); 

html2canvas( data ).then(canvas => {  

  var imgWidth =297;
  var pageHeight = 210;    
  var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;  
  var heightLeft = imgHeight;  
  const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')  
  var doc = new jspdf('l', 'mm', 'a4'); // A4 size page of PDF  
  var position = 2;  
  doc.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);

  const file = doc.output('datauristring');

  const filePath = Date.now().toString();
  const fileRef = this.storage.ref('/test/' + filePath);
  const task = this.storage.upload('/test/' + filePath, file);
  this.uploadPercent = task.percentageChanges();
  task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
  finalize(() => {
  this.downloadURL = fileRef.getDownloadURL();
  this.downloadURL.subscribe(url => this.url = url
  )
  }))
  .subscribe();
  });  
  }   
  }
```

I have this error :

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): 
>   FirebaseStorageError:
>    {"code_":"storage/invalid-argument",
>   "message_":
>   "Firebase Storage: Invalid argument in `put` at index 0:
>    Expected Blob or File.",
>   "serverResponse_":null,"name_":"FirebaseError"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer works for me.

html2canvas( data ).then(canvas => {

```
  var imgWidth =297;
  var pageHeight = 210;    
  var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;  
  var heightLeft = imgHeight;  
  const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')  
  var doc = new jspdf('l', 'mm', 'a4'); // A4 size page of PDF  
  var position = 2;  
  doc.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);

  const file = doc.output("blob");

  const filePath = Date.now().toString();
  const fileRef = this.storage.ref('/test/' + filePath+'.pdf');
  const task = this.storage.upload('/test/' + filePath+'.pdf', file);
  this.uploadPercent = task.percentageChanges();
  task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
  finalize(() => {
  this.downloadURL = fileRef.getDownloadURL();
  this.downloadURL.subscribe(url => this.url = url
  )
  }))
  .subscribe();
  });  
  }   
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of const task = this.storage.upload('/test/' + filePath, file) 
You need to pass to a name with extension for example 
const task = this.storage.upload('/test/' + filePath+'myfile.pdf',file);
 Because filepath is not a blob or file its a string

Comment: i think the problem is in doc.output(), no ?